# Ember generated service raising error on injection

Tags: ember.js, service, controller, inject

I am brand new to EmberJS, and am going through a tutorial. I am at the part of the tutorial that starts talking about creating services and injecting them into your controllers (I'm not 100% sure if its a controller, but I'm coming from AngularJS, and it seems pretty similar).

In the terminal in my Ember project, I run the command `ember g service authentication`. I can see that the service was created in the services directory of my app in the file `authentication.js`. When I try injecting it into my controller however, I get this issue in the browser when I serve up the app locally,

```
Error: Assertion Failed: Attempting to inject an unknown injection: 'service:authentication
```

Could this be because I am using a version of Ember that is newer than in the tutorial, and there is a different way to inject services now? I ask that because this is the syntax of the service in the tutorial

```
import ember from 'ember'

export default Ember.Service.extend({
  records: []
});
```

and this is the syntax of what I have now, auto-created when the project was built with `ember new`

```
import Service from '@ember/service';

export default Service.extend({
  records: []
});
```

org.js "Where service is being injected"

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({

  authentication: Ember.inject.service(),

  setupController(controller) {
    this._super(...arguments);
  }
});
```

Comment: The code you shared is fine, one thing you could change is using `import { inject } from "@ember/service";` instead of relying on the global `Ember.inject.service`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ember version 2.16, you can leverage javascript module api for importing.
[Refer this blog post](https://emberjs.com/blog/2017/10/11/ember-2-16-released.html#toc_ember-js-modules-api)
[Refer this full list](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/master/text/0176-javascript-module-api.md)

if your ember version is below 2.16, then

```
import ember from 'ember'

export default Ember.Service.extend({
  records: []
});
```

if ember version is >= 2.16 then the below is the right way to import,

```
import Service from '@ember/service';

export default Service.extend({
  records: []
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks you everyone for all the information about EmberJS.However It turns out all I needed to do was restart my local server -.-

Comment: I was getting the same error message and restarting the server solved the issue. Thanks for writing it down here.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are using Ember 2.16 (as others have answered it uses the new components modularization and the tutorial you are following looks like 2.15 or prior, as you have also mentioned in your post).

It makes sense that you should use new modules in your new route too:

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
import { inject as service } from "@ember/service";

export default Route.extend({
  authentication: service()
});
```

One acclaration: the code you are showing is a `route` class (there are `controllers` on the route hierarchy, and also there are `components` that are not part of the route hierarchy). You will be able to inject your brand-new service in any of the mentioned levels.